# Same set of numbers printed when using random generation function

Tags: c++

I have a code that prints 5x5 matrices of random numbers 10 times .I have used mt19937 generator. The problem is it prints the same set of 25 random numbers each time the main loop iterates(int S).How can I make this random?

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generator(device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,  10100);

for (int S = 0; S < 10; S++)
{
    


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
    {

    


        for (size_t i = 0; i < dataBitsPerBlock; ++i)
        {
            
            inputDataBits[i] = distribution(generator) % 2;       //generates input data stream
        }

        blockData.push_back(inputDataBits);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << blockData[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    cout << endl<< endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "main" loop? Is this code inside `main()` or a separate function?

Comment: You need to post a [mre], with all `#include`s and all function/variable declarations necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You never _reset_ `blockData`, you just keep pushing back new stuff onto it. The first five bits of the first five elements will always be the same as long as you never change or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wring with random data being generated. Only issue is with the code for testing it. The outer most loops runs 10 times and you expect 10 different blocks but the block creation logic only `push_back` rows so you actually append the next block under first one and once again print the first block itself. You just need to call `clear()` on `blockData` after printing it.

For better understanding I am giving complete code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 10100);

    int numberOfBlocks = 5;
    const int dataBitsPerBlock = 5;
    std::vector<int> inputDataBits(dataBitsPerBlock);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> blockData;

    for (int S = 0; S < 10; S++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < dataBitsPerBlock; ++i)
            {
                inputDataBits[i] = distribution(generator) % 2;       //generates input data stream
            }

            blockData.push_back(inputDataBits);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                std::cout << blockData[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << endl;

        }
        blockData.clear(); // This is the solution.
        std::cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```